# JavaScript Binary Search Tree in-order traversal returning undefined as part of answer

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

I'm writing a recursive in-order traversal method for a BST in JS. The method is supposed to return numerical leaf values in order within an array. So far, my written method does that. But in addition to the in-order numbers, it also returns 3 'undefined' at the end of my array as well. My code for the in order method is here:

```
this.inorder = function(){
        let travArr = [];

        function recurTrav(node){
            if(node.left == null && node.right == null){
                console.log("leaf: " + node.value);
                return node.value;
            }
            else if(node.right == null){
                console.log("right is null, val: " + node.value);
                travArr.push(recurTrav(node.left));
                travArr.push(node.value);
            }
            else if(node.left == null){
                console.log("left is null, val:" + node.value);
                travArr.push(node.value);
                travArr.push(recurTrav(node.right));
            }
            else{
                console.log("no nulls:");
                travArr.push(recurTrav(node.left));
                travArr.push(node.value);
                travArr.push(recurTrav(node.right));
            }
        }

        recurTrav(this.root);
        return travArr;
}
```

The this.root is the root node of the BST. I have an add method that I didn't include here, for the sake of simplicity. Nodes have a value, left, and right property.

If I added the numbers 3, 2, 5, 6, 14, 8 to my BST in that order, my `.inorder()` method returns `[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 14, undefined, undefined, undefined]` for some reason. I can't figure out where those 3 undefined's are coming from. I think it might be because of my travArr.push(), which might potentially return 'undefined'.

I realize I could probably just do some array manipulation to take those 'undefined' out, but I really want to understand how I wrote my code wrong in the first place. If including my full code for my BST is easier, just let me know and I'll include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look to this part:

```
function recurTrav(node) {
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null){
        console.log("leaf: " + node.value);
        return node.value;                                 // returns a value
    } else if(node.right == null){
        console.log("right is null, val: " + node.value);
        travArr.push(recurTrav(node.left));                // <------ could take undefined
        travArr.push(node.value);                          // no return until end of funct
    }
    //..
    // missing return, takes default return value.
}
```

Solution: Push only if necessary and call function without using the result for pushing.

```
function recurTrav(node) {
    if (!node.left && !node.right) {                      // falsy check incl undefined/null
        console.log("leaf: " + node.value);
        travArr.push(node.value);
        return;                                           // omit else parts
    }                                                     // with early returns
    if (!node.right) {
        console.log("right is null, val: " + node.value);
        recurTrav(node.left);
        travArr.push(node.value);
        return;
    }
    if (!node.left) {
        console.log("left is null, val:" + node.value);
        travArr.push(node.value);
        recurTrav(node.right);
        return;
    }
    console.log("no nulls:");
    recurTrav(node.left);
    travArr.push(node.value);
    recurTrav(node.right);
}
```

Comment: Hey there again Nina! This totally solved my problem, thanks so much again, you really are a life saver. But again, I'm still pretty confused as to why my original code was adding 3 "undefineds" so randomly? Was it because an Array.push() returns an undefined by default or something? I don't see how it could've been the "return node.value", since that actually returns a value

Comment: it returns the result of the function (default `undefined`) in cases of not returning the value.

Comment: so it was the "if(node.left == null)" and "if(node.right == null)" blocks that were returning the "undefined"?

Comment: also, out of curiousity, why did you drop the "else" parts? Is it faster/less memory intensive the way you wrote it?

Comment: no, the end of the function returns `undefined`. it has nothing to do with the check. it is just the standard ending of the (every) function in javascript whichg returns `undfined`, if not using `return` with a different value.

Comment: ad else: it is easier to maintain without chaining else parts.

Answer (score 1):

Given a simple `Node` constructor

```
class Node
{ constructor (value, left, right)
  { this.value = value
    this.left = left
    this.right = right
  } 
}
```

And a simple `Tree` constructor

```
class Tree
{ constructor (root)
  { this.root = root
  }

  ...
}
```

We can implement `Tree#inorder` without the need to null-check `left` and `right` branches individually

```
inorder ()
{ if (this.root === undefined)
    return []

  else
    return [ ...new Tree (this.root.left).inorder ()
           , this.root.value
           , ...new Tree (this.root.right).inorder ()
           ]
}
```

Run the complete program below to verify the results in your own browser

```js
class Node
{ constructor (value, left, right)
  { this.value = value
    this.left = left
    this.right = right
  } 
}

class Tree
{ constructor (root)
  { this.root = root
  }

  inorder ()
  { if (this.root === undefined)
      return []

    else
      return [ ...new Tree (this.root.left).inorder ()
             , this.root.value
             , ...new Tree (this.root.right).inorder ()
             ]
  }
}

const n =
  new Node 
  ( 3
  , new Node
      ( 2
      , new Node (1)
      , undefined
      )
  , new Node
      ( 6
      , new Node
          ( 4
          , undefined
          , new Node (5)
          )
      , new Node (7)
      )
  )

const t =
  new Tree (n)

console.log (t.inorder ())
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```